# Can you store an android application in google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

i am new to cloud platform services. I have developed a simple android application that has AR element to it. Is it possible to store the app here, and download the app to my phone whenerver i want or is there certain steps that i have to follow? If not, may i know any alternatives to store an app in cloud?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can upload any kind of files to Google Cloud Platform, please refer to [this link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-basics) from the Official Documentation to accomplish that.

Here are the steps in a simple way:

1. Open the Cloud Storage browser in the Google Cloud Platform Console.
2. In the list of buckets, click on the bucket you want to upload an object to.
3. Click Upload Files or Upload Folder at the top of the Console.

   Note: Folder uploads are only supported in Chrome. File uploads are supported in all browsers.
4. In the dialog that appears, select the file or folder you want to upload to your bucket.
5. Click Open.

If you want to use `gsutil` and `cp` then please refer to [this link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp).

> The gsutil cp command allows you to copy data between your local file
>   system and the cloud, copy data within the cloud, and copy data
>   between cloud storage providers. For example, to copy all text files
>   from the local directory to a bucket you could do:

Example:
`gsutil cp *.txt gs://my-bucket`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the possibility to set up your own F-Droid repository.
(https://f-droid.org/en/)

This requires quite a bit of fiddling but in the end you will basically have your own "Playstore" where you can upload and publish your own apps to whomever you want.